# iframe with google chart - making it responsive and borderless

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-fusion-tables

i'm trying to work with a google chart from google fusion tables.
it works fine but i have 2 main issues...

1) it's not responsive
2) i don't want any border but even if i tried to remove it, it still shows it

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waaEXg

i tried to embed the iframe inside an outer div, this is the css for it

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

what's wrong with it? why it's not responsive? why does the border is still there?

Comment: The border is inside the iframe so outside style won't apply. The lack of responsiveness comes from the fact that fixed dimensions are part of the src attribute (check at the very end).

Comment: so how should i fix both things?

Comment: Unless there's something in the documentation about styling the contents of the iframe, there wouldn't be a whole lot to do about the border. Since I'm not aware of much of the details of this Google feature, my choice would probably be to check the window width with jQuery and then pasting the `src` attribute dynamically with this value. Leaving the values out altogether doesn't seem to be an option in any case.